# Range Define name... won't accept name

Tags: excel, range, rename

This is very weird. But i think i might missing something basic. I am trying to name a range with unique name that combines letters and numbers.

Here's what happens:

> 1. I select a range (click and drag a number of cells)
> 2. Right click -> Define name...
> 3. Enter ABC123 and click Ok.
> 4. Error.

```
The name you entered is not valid.
Reasons for this can include:
-name does not begin with a letter or underscore
-name contains a space or other invalid characters
-name conflicts with an Excel built in name of name of the another object in workbook
```

If I delete 123 and left with ABC then there is no error. The moment I add numbers to the name, error cames up. ABC1, XYZ2, all gives error.

Comment: It is reserved as it is already a cell reference. See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/07/illegal-range-names/

Comment: Understood. Didn't realize ABC1 can be a cell reference. lol

Comment: I have fallen foul of that too in the past.

Comment: anyway ty for ur comment. if u put as answer then i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies,as i should actually have put it here in the first place.
It is already reserved as cell reference so you cannot use it as a name for a named range. Some examples of what isn't allowed are here:

[Illegal range names](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/07/illegal-range-names/)